# Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx

Tags: javascript, testing, adonis.js, japa

when I work with japa test runner adonisJs 5 my test failed and got this error:

```
× Uncaught exception

   Transaction query already complete, run with DEBUG=knex:tx for more info


     1  completedError
       node_modules/knex/lib/execution/transaction.js:396

     2  anonymous
       node_modules/knex/lib/execution/transaction.js:362

     3  Client_MySQL2.trxClient.query
       node_modules/knex/lib/execution/transaction.js:358

     4  Runner.query
       node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:123

     5  ensureConnectionCallback
       node_modules/knex/lib/execution/internal/ensure-connection-callback.js:13

     6  Runner.ensureConnection
       node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:300

     7  Runner.run
       node_modules/knex/lib/execution/runner.js:30

     8  QueryRunner.executeQuery
       node_modules/@adonisjs/lucid/build/src/QueryRunner/index.js:78
```

I don't know why I get this error in some of my tests
in some of i don't

japa test runner adonisJs 5

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and the issue for me was a missing **await** on a database call that returned a promise in one of my assertions,

so by the time the response was returned the global transaction in the test suite had already been rolled back

Once I added the await, the error was resolved, so I suggest you double check any async calls in your tests which you may not be awaiting a response for.